# JS: Submit or transfer input values to another HTML File?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**Description:**

I created this workflow: PHP loads content from a database to certain textareas. The user can edit and save content.

I created a HTML template which can be printed directly from the web browser.

So the user clicks on the "Print" button and gets a nice template which can be printed directly from the browser.

**Goal:**

I want jQuery or JavaScript to load / transfer the content from the input fields to another HTML document on the server, in certain div-classes.

Is this generally possible or a good idea?

Afterwards, this becomes loaded and the print dialogue of the web browser will be opened.

**Present Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".print-button" ).click(function() {
      $('html').load("./views/print/template-1.html");
      setTimeout(function(){
        window.print(); 
      }, 1000);
    })

    window.onafterprint = function(e){
        $(window).off('mousemove', window.onafterprint);
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    };

});
```

So template-1.html should get the data.

Comment: Would you be able to store the data in the URL, then retrieve it on the other HTML site?

Comment: Or you can use **localstorage** to store and retrieve data.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll go for PHP or the session storage.
I personally don't like storing data in URLs except keys.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I think it would be a good idea to support the build in functionality of the browser. The user should be able to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or use the menu to open the print dialog.

My suggestion would be to create a `<div>` element that is hidden. On some event, like when the `<textarea>` is changed, update the `<div>` element with the content. Create a stylesheet for printing where the `<div>` element is visible and hide elements that are not for printing (like the `<textarea>`).

Comment: Thank you for this hint, I will consider this.

Answer (score 1):

As per the description, you have mentioned that you are allowing PHP to load the data in certain text-areas and allows user to update that, so when you update this data, it'll be saving into the database for that particular text-area.

What best you can do here is keep one unique key for that shown data and when you redirect the page bind the unique key along with the page URL, so using that key on the new page where you have the template, you can get the data using select query and you can print the data wherever you want.

Afterwords on print click, the template will have the data filled in and so the user will be able to download/print the template with data, the way you wanted.

**Or**

If you don't want to use the PHP for getting data on the new document, you can simply pass the data object in localstorage by using below way :

```
var content= <your data Object>;
localStorage.setItem('print_content', content);
```

Now before loading the dialogue, get the data from localstorage variable and print it to div or area wherever you want. For getting data from localstorage use below way:

```
var printData = localStorage.getItem('print_content');
```

using printData var, you'll be able to get the data and using jQuery syntax you'll be able to append or display the data to div.